# How to create a local virtual IP camera that can be accessed from other software

Tags: ip, virtual, labview

I need to create several local virtual IP Cameras for a project I'm making. I have tried several software, and the closest I have gotten was with magic camera, because it would let me create a virtual camera, but it wont let me assign a source to that camera. I need to assign an IP address and a username with a password, so that I access the IP camera's video and use that virtual camera in a program I'm developing. the thing is that the Camera's brand is not supported by Labview, so I need to use a virtual local camera to use these cameras (3S Vision IP Cameras).
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

From the National Instruments Support Knowledgebase:

**Connecting to an Arbitrary MJPEG IP Camera with IMAQdx Using Third Party Virtual Camera Emulator**

http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/9446A8C25CC99F7586257A56004D513D

Comment: I already tried that approach, but it didn't work. Can you please tell me how to do this with magic camera?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the options for using an IP cameras in LabVIEW as of 2019:
<sup>(in case someone like me still need this)</sup>

- **Use Vision Acquisition Software 14.5 (February 2015)**
  <sup>(with LabVIEW 2014 SP1 and Vision Development Module 2014-2017 SP1)</sup>

  **Pros:**

  - Official, native support;
  - Any # of cameras.

  **Cons:**

  - You lose all the features introduced in newer versions of LabVIEW;
  - Cameras must support and be configured to stream in MJPEG over HTTP.

  **Additional info:**

  It's the last version to [support arbitrary IP cameras](http://download.ni.com/support/softlib/vision/Vision%20Acquisition%20Software/February%202015/VisionAcqReleaseNotes.html). [Basler and Axis IP cameras were supported until VAS 19.0](http://download.ni.com/support/softlib/vision/Vision%20Acquisition%20Software/18.5/readme_VAS.html).

  Cameras in the same subnet should be detected automatically. If cameras are in another network, [you can try to add them manually](https://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/IP-camera-adaptor-Labview/m-p/2798828#M821191) as follows:

  1. Go to the `%Public%\Documents\National Instruments\NI-IMAQdx\Data\` folder;
  2. Open or create a file `IPCameras.ini` in a text editor;
  3. If creating, place an `IPCameras` section on a first line:

     ```
     [IPCameras]
     ```
  4. Add a line for each camera in a following format:

     ```
     cameraSerialNumber = IPAddress, MJPEG stream URL, camera brand, camera description
     ```
  5. Save your changes and restart NI MAX.
- **Use DirectShow device (webcam) emulator**

  [NI-IMAQdx driver supports USB 2.0 cameras through the DirectShow interface](https://knowledge.ni.com/KnowledgeArticleDetails?id=kA00Z000000P6COSA0&l=en-US). By using software which creates such interface for IP cameras, they can be used as regular USB 2.0 cameras.

  There are multiple tools available:

  - [IP Video Source](http://alax.info/blog/1216)

    **Pros:**

    - Free;
    - Any # of cameras.

    **Cons:**

    - Each camera must be added manually through emulator's settings;
    - Each camera's resolution must be set manually in emulator's settings;
    - Cameras must support and be configured to stream in MJPEG over HTTP(S);
    - 32/64-bit versions [work independently of each other](http://alax.info/blog/1223). NI MAX is a 32-bit application, so it won't show cameras emulated by 64-bit tool. However, they are still detected and can be used in LabVIEW with IMAQdx VIs.

    **Additional info:**

    Camera's alias displayed in LabVIEW can be changed in a following way:

    1. Go to the `%Public%\Documents\National Instruments\NI-IMAQdx\Data\` folder;
    2. Select one of `camX.iid` files and open it in a text editor;
    3. Find an attribute `InterfaceName` and set its value to a desired name. See `Vendor` attribute's value for a name you set to that camera in emulator's settings;
    4. Save your changes and rename this file to the same name;
    5. Restart LabVIEW.
  - [Moonware Universal](http://www.webcamxp.com/download.aspx) [Source Filter](https://www.netcamstudio.com/Download) [[more info](https://community.netcamstudio.com/t/moonware-universal-source-filter-directshow-filter/1156)]

    **Pros:**

    - Supports JPEG/MJPEG/MPEG4/H264 over HTTP/RTSP;
    - Hardware decoding;
    - Low latency;
    - Multiple cameras.

    **Cons:**

    - 32-bit only. 64-bit version [is not likely](https://community.netcamstudio.com/t/moonware-universal-source-filter-and-obs-studio/1797/4) [to happen](https://community.netcamstudio.com/t/moonware-universal-source-filter-directshow-filter/1156/11);
    - Adds a watermark to an image (free version) / Paid: $49 per PC (no watermark);
    - Each camera must be added manually through emulator's settings.
  - [and](https://azcendant.com/IPCamOverview.html) [more](http://ip-webcam.appspot.com)
- **Use [Multimedia for LabVIEW](http://sine.ni.com/nips/cds/view/p/lang/en/nid/213420) add-on**

  **Pros:**

  - Native interface (LabVIEW API for FFmpeg libraries);
  - [Supports most codecs and protocols](http://www.ffmpeg.org/general.html);
  - Any # of cameras;
  - Full control over data acquisition and processing (down to individual FFmpeg options).

  **Cons:**

  - Paid: $949 per PC (developer license), $19 per PC (runtime license), 30 days trial;
  - Lower-level analog of NI-IMAQdx driver (see more complicated).
- **Use [libVLC](https://wiki.videolan.org/LibVLC/) to receive images from a camera**
  <sup>(or another similar library)</sup>

  **Pros:**

  - Free;
  - [Supports most codecs](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_Features_Formats/) and [protocols](https://wiki.videolan.org/Protocols/);
  - Possibility of hardware decoding ([depends on library usage](https://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/doc/doxygen/html/group__libvlc__media__player.html#ga612605f2e5c638d9f4ed59021d714bf0));
  - Any # of cameras.

  **Cons:**

  - You'll have to interface with `libVLC` library directly through the `Call Library` function node;
  - [To receive video frame by frame you'll have to write a simple C library](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=ru&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.labviewportal.org%2Fviewtopic.php%3Ff%3D22%26t%3D7379%23p61866) which will be called by `libVLC` to provide a frame (see example below in a linked thread).